# Newton method - when the convergence order of $f(x)$ is 3?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Let $f(x)\in C^4(\mathbb{R}),r\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(r)=0$.

Find conditions such that the convergence order of  $f(x)$ is $3$ ?

My attempt:

Denote $x_{n+1}=r+e_{n+1}$.

$\displaystyle x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\implies r+e_{n+1} = r+e_{n}-\frac{f(r+e_{n})}{f'(r+e_{n})}$

$\displaystyle e_{n+1} = e_{n}-\frac{f(r+e_{n})}{f'(r+e_{n})}$.

Using Taylor series:

$\displaystyle e_{n+1} = e_{n}-\frac{f(r)+e_nf'(r)+\frac{1}{2!}(e_n)^2f''(r)+\frac{1}{3!}(e_n)^3f'''(r)}{e_nf'(r)+\frac{1}{2!}(e_n)^2f''(r)+\frac{1}{3!}(e_n)^3f'''(r)+\frac{1}{4!}(e_n)^4f''''(r)}$

In case $f''(r)=0$ and $e_n$ is very small , hence $(e_n)^4\ll e_n$

$\displaystyle e_{n+1} = \frac{e_n(f'(r)+(e_n)^2f'''(r))-e_nf'(r)}{f'(r)+(e_n)^2f'''(r)} \implies e_{n+1}=(e_n)^3\frac{f'''(r)}{f'(r)}$

In conclusion , the conditions id that $f''(r)=0$ , is my solution correct ?

Thanks !

Comment: One can systematically achieve this condition by applying the Newton method to $g=f/\sqrt{|f'|}$. This is then the Halley method for $f$.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct but you were lucky in the process... It is not at all clear that you can just use independent Taylor expansions in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective should be to convince the reader that you have thought of everything and that you know exactly why your reasoning is correct. To this end, it helps to support the mathematical reasoning with descriptive language. I shall demonstrate.

---

We begin with some background information that may or may not be necessary. A functional iteration is any iteration of the form
$$x_{n+1} = g(x_n).$$
Newton's method corresponds to the special case of 
$$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$ 
Suppose that functional iteration is convergent with limit $r$ and that $g$ is continuous, then $$r = g(r)$$ simply because
$$
r = \lim x_{n+1} = \lim g(x_n) = g(\lim x_n) = g(r).
$$
We see that the limit $r$ must be a fixed point of the function $g$. For this reason, functional iterations are also known as fixed point iterations. We shall now concern ourselves with the convergence of functional iterations. We shall assume that the underlying function $g$ is sufficiently smooth and we shall apply Taylor's theorem as needed. In particular, suppose that $g$ is $C^3$ and that $r$ is a fixed point of $g$, then there is at least one $\xi_n$ between $r$ and $x_n$ such that
$$ e_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - r = g(x_n) - g(r) = g'(r)e_n + \frac{1}{2}g''(r) e_n^2 + \frac{1}{6} g'''(\xi_n) e_n^3.$$
We observe that the values of $g^{(j)}(r)$ must play a pivotal role in the analysis of the functional iteration. In particular, if $$g'(r) = g''(r) = 0,$$ then
$$ e_{n+1} = \frac{1}{6} g'''(\xi_n) e_n^3$$
Now let us suppose that the iteration converges to $r$, then $\xi_n$ will converge to $r$ by the squeeze lemma. By the assumed continuity of $g'''$ we have 
$$ \frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^3} \rightarrow \frac{1}{6} g'''(r)$$
Now if $g'''(r) \not = 0$, then this shows that the order of convergence is $p=3$. This completes the survey of the necessary background information.

---

We are now ready to consider the special case of Newton's method. We shall assume that $f$ is $C^4$, that $f(r) = 0$ and that $f'(r) \not = 0$ so that $g$ is $C^3$ at least in a neighborhood of $r$. 
We apply the standard rules of differentiation and obtain that
$$ g'(x) = f(x) \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}.$$
Since $g'(r) = 0$ we immediately understand why Newton's method often exhibits quadratic convergence, i.e. order $p=2$. Moreover,
$$ g''(x) = f'(x) \frac{ f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} + f(x) \left( \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} \right)'. $$
We see that 
$$ g''(r) = \frac{f''(r)}{f'(r)}.$$
We conclude that $g''(r) = 0$ if and only if $f''(r) = 0$.

---

In summary, if $f''(r) = 0$, and if the functional iteration convergences to $r$, then the convergence will have order at least $p=3$.